# Tomcat 7 data source configuration for MySQL database

Tags: hibernate, tomcat

I am trying to create a data source in Tomcat 7 for using in Hibernate code.

Tomcat 7.0.47

Hibernate: 4.2.7.Final

OS: Windows 7

**context.xml**

Used the documetation [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) to configure the data source in the `context.xml` file.

context.xml location: <%Tomcat HOME%>\conf

```
<Resource name="hmsDS" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                   maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
                   username="root" password="root" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                   url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/hms"/>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/hmsDS</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <mapping class="org.srs.hms.entity.TestEntity"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**On starting TomCat**
Console output:

```
Jan 10, 2014 5:13:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: D:\InstalledSoftware\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.3.4\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft CHESS\bin\;D:\InstalledSoftware\Python25;D:\InstalledSoftware\GNUstep\bin;D:\InstalledSoftware\GNUstep\GNUstep\System\Tools;D:\InstalledSoftware\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin;"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge";.
Jan 10, 2014 5:13:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 10, 2014 5:13:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 10, 2014 5:13:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 436 ms
Jan 10, 2014 5:13:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 10, 2014 5:13:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Jan 10, 2014 5:13:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 10, 2014 5:13:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 10, 2014 5:13:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 353 ms
```

**Code that accesses the database:**

```
public class Test {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();        
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        Session sess = sessionFactory.openSession();
        sess.beginTransaction();

        sess.save(new TestEntity());
        sess.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

**On accessing the database from the code above I get the following error:**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException: Error parsing JNDI name [java:comp/env/hmsDS]
    at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.parseName(JndiServiceImpl.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1822)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1780)
    at org.srs.hms.dao.CommonDAO.<clinit>(CommonDAO.java:28)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:344)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getNameParser(InitialContext.java:499)
    at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.parseName(JndiServiceImpl.java:86)
    ... 40 more
```

**Number of connection to the database is '2'**

Query: show global status where variable_name = 'Threads_connected';

I ran the query after running my test class.  The query result = 2

**Question 1**  I am not seeing any connection pool related debug/trace statement in the logs when I restart Tomcat after configuring the data source.  I was expecting info related to creation of the connections in the connection pool etc. The logging level is set at 'TRACE'.  Is this normal?

**Question 2** How do I resolve the error shown above?

**Update 1 - web.xml**

web.xml is updated with the following entry inside  tag
  
      DB Connection
      hmsDB
      javax.sql.DataSource
      Container

This change didn't help either.

**Update 2**
I could finally get it working with the suggestions in the comments section.  Thanks everyone.

Here is the result of my analysis:

Entry in `web.xml` is NOT required.  Entry made in `context.xml` is good enough to get it working.  Initially I was testing with a stand alone Java class (main method), hence the error mentioned above.  It won't work as the stand alone class with not have access to the required context outside the container; an obvious rookie mistake by me.  When I tested from the UI, it worked fine.

Special thanks to Joe Rinehart for asking the right question! +1

Comment: You've left out your `web.xml` configuration. Did you follow the how-to page, doing that as well (a `resource-ref`?)

Comment: I deliberately left the web.xml configuration as I thought it is not required as I am working at the hibernate level only.  To instruct the container to create the database connection pool, is context.xml configuration not sufficient?

Comment: Updating web.xml doesn't seem to help; same error reported.  I've updated my original post with this info.

Comment: How/in what container are you executing the Test class?

Comment: Not sure if this could be affecting it, but you are missing the port in your jndi url configuration: url="jdbc:mysql://<server>:<port>/<database>"

Comment: I also use in context.xml: <ResourceLink name="jdbc/xxx"
         type="javax.sql.DataSource"
         global="jdbc/xxx"/>

Comment: @Joe Rinehart, could you move your comment to an answer please?  Your question helped me to understand why my test failed, even though my configuration was correct.

Comment: @PhantomReference - Done and done, just improved wording a bit.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may not be executing your test class within the same context/container/jvm as Tomcat itself. I'd check that out.